# How do I do a simple next() method on a M2M in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cycle, python-itertools

I have two models with a many to many, Group and Individual.

I can access group.individuals and get a list of the related individuals. I have a 'last_individual_id' column on the Group models to keep track of the Last used individual. With this information I was wandering how get get the next individual for a Group.

I thought of getting the id's for the Individuals and using itertools.cycle but i can't specify the start point. Plus that may be a slow way to do it if I can just do it properly in SQLAlchemy.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I feel like I will be embarrassed at how simple the answer is... but I didn't have caffeine today!

Thanks

Comment: You don't mean `next()` in the sense of iterators, do you?

Comment: You did not state the problem very clearly. What would be the corresponding sql, something like `select individual.id from individuals join groups on (individual.group_id = group.id) where individual.id > groups.last_individual_id order by individual.id limit 1`?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using itertools.dropwhile (but this may be limited as the scope of your desired solution, as it is not clear, also itertools.dropwhile doesn't infinitely cycle through your list like itertools.cycle does).

You didn't provide a lot of detail of your data model.  I'll presume that group.individuals returns a list of individuals objects and the '.id' property represents each individual's id number.  For example, say your looking for individual id 7, within the list of group.individuals:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
for item in dropwhile(lambda x: x.id != 7, group.individuals):
    print item
```

This will go through the list until it finds id=7 (or more acurately, until x.id != 7, as itertools.dropwhile won't return anything until the first False test), then it will start returning individuals objects from the list.  So if the id's from that list are like: [1, 19, 5, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5] this would return:  7 2 4 5.

For your purposes it sounds like you would ignore the first returned response, and then use the responses after.

Another alternative is to iterate through your original list of group.individuals to find the index of the id you want, then just increment the index - this would also allow you to start the index over at 0 if your calculated index exceeds your list, for example:

```
def nextrecord(recordlist, value):    
    for i in range(len(recordlist)):        
        if recordlist[i].id == value:
            newindex = i + 1
            break
    if newindex >= len(recordlist):
        newindex = 0    
    return recordlist[newindex]

print nextrecord(group.individuals, 7)
```

But, of course, this is more discrete, and isn't iterable.  There are probably lots of other ways to approach this (including making my function iterable) but I also haven't had my caffeine yet!

Comment: Raceymans second solution provided my answer. I had cleared my browser cookies so I can't choose it as the answer. If some admin can select his response and delete this comment we can clean this one up. Than